# outlook contract Signature

Tags: outlook-2003

I'm working with outlook and I got a problem.

I dont know why and how, but my outlook project lost the Certificate.
so I go on vba->tool->tools->Personal Digital Signature

I set a Certificate.

I try to save and got an error.

in french "Une erreur est survenue lors de la signature du projet. Le projet non-signé a été enregistré."

this means : an error occurred during Signature of the project. the project unsigned has been saved.

after the digital sign is empty.

and I still cant use macro.

I dont know what to do.

help me

Comment: I found a way,
I use an old VbaProject.OTM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way: I use an old VbaProject.OTM.